Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info' from assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
I am trying to migrate from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 8.0. Now I'm getting this error while running the application
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info' from assembly 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=7.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593'.
Please help

You need to start with Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2

^^ Same. Take one step after the other. Maybe skip the odd STS but from zero to hero will just have too many breaking changes at once.

MvcJsonOptions was removed in .NET Core 3.0 and is not available in versions newer than 2.2 See the "Applies to"-Table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#applies-to
In case you are using Swashbuckle, this thread suggested updating to the newest Swashbuckle version should help: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.0.0.0

I installed Swashbuckle with and without Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json. But getting the same error

In my opinion, it is good to migrate in intermediate versions. Because from a far old version to 8 there are many advancements and support issues.
